# How to access a field in one class from another?

Tags: c#

**Note that this is not an inheritance or interface.**

I have a class `HP`

```
public class HP
{
    public int Base;

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            //Need to access Monster.Level to calculate total HP.
        }
    }
}
```

And a class `Monster` calling `HP`

```
public class Monster
{
    public HP hp;
    public int Level;
}
```

How can I access Monster.Level from HP?

I tried to pass `Level` by reference to `HP` upon instantiating.

```
public class HP
{
    private ref int Level;

    public A(ref i)
    {
        Level=i;
    }
}
```

But I want to keep A as simple and clean as possible.

The reason I don't want to pass the level upon creation is `Level` is a constantly changing valuable, I'll will then have to "update" the `HP` every time the monster gains a level or something, which is NOT a efficient way to do things.

And there are other things accessing `Level`, such as `Attack` and `Damage`, etc.

I currently has a method within `HP`, `Attack`, `Damage`, etc., taking the `Level` as a parameter.

```
public int Value(int lv)
{
    return Base+10*lv;
}
```

But according to the a little bit of SOLID principle I know, this is a **VERY BAD** coding!

Comment: In your code `B` is not a subclass of `A`. You've used composition, not inheritance.

Comment: If your question isn't about inheritance, it would help immensely if you weren't using terms from inheritance such as "subclass" and "base class"

Comment: I've edited your question title since (as you yourself have made clear) there is no inheritance.

Comment: You either are looking for `static` member, or don't actually understand the concept of `class`

Comment: Now that we've cleared that this isn't inheritance, can you please let us know what problem you're trying to solve by accessing `B.i` from `A`?

Comment: @Rafalon - generally speaking, `static` is a bad idea.

Comment: In *general*, multiple `B`s may contain a reference to the *same* `A`. Are you working in a situation where that (should be/is) prevented? Is this perhaps some kind of ownership model? It would probably help if the dummy names chosen reflected *some* aspects of the real model.

Comment: I think you're missunderstanding the concept of classes. Let's use `Bottle` and `Drink` instead of `A` and `B` . You defined that a `Bottle` has a `Drink` and therefore contains a property of type `Drink` that it can access. However a `Drink` probably has other properties like `Color`, `Amount_Sugar` etc since it has nothing to do with a `Bottle`. That means if you want to access the `Bottle` from your drink you need to either have a property e.g. `Container` with type `Bottle` inside your `Drink` class or a method e.g. `Fill` that receives the `Bottle` as a parameter if you need to access it.

Comment: @Noob001 Is there any chllange in passing an instance of `B` into the `A::DoSomething()` or into `A` during its instanciation?

Comment: Thanks for everybody's response, which is "too fast"! ^o^|||  I had edited my questions as fast as possible, please take a look, thanks!

Comment: I simply think `HP.Value` should not be a readonly property. It should be a Function that takes an Argument `level`. Simple as that.

Comment: This now sounds like a job for inheritance. We don't you think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to avoid inheritance, then this should do the kind of thing that you want:

```
public class Monster
{
    public int Level { get; set; }
    private MonsterHitPointCalculator _hp = new MonsterHitPointCalculator();
    public int HitPoints => _hp.Compute(this);
}

public class MonsterHitPointCalculator
{
    private int _base = 42;
    public int Compute(Monster actor) => this._base + 10 * actor.Level;
}
```

But, I think, in your case inheritance is the way to go. Try this instead:

```
public abstract class Actor
{
    protected int _base = 42;
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public virtual int HitPoints => _base + this.Level;
}

public class Monster : Actor
{
    public override int HitPoints => _base + 10 * this.Level;
}

public class Human : Actor
{
    public override int HitPoints => base.HitPoints + 20;
}
```

In both cases the following code can be used to get the same example result:

```
var monster = new Monster();

monster.Level = 1;
Console.WriteLine(monster.HitPoints);

monster.Level = 2;
Console.WriteLine(monster.HitPoints);
```

It outputs:

```
52
62
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! But I don't really know how to employ this into my code! Because in reality, it's MUCH MORE complicated! If possible, I would like it to be calculated "within" `HP` class or `Attack`, `Damage` class for that matter. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Noob001 - I'd suggest that you now ask a second question and include more of the detail and other classes. Don't just edit this question - it's best to make a new one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you called `HP` is more of a `HPCalculator` responsible of calculating Monster's HP based on this Moster's level and possibly other data in the future, I think it seem crucial for such `HPCalculator` to have access to the `Monster` of which health it calculates.

In `C#` classes are done by references not by values meaning you can in no problem have something like this:

```cs
public class Monster{
    public HP hp;
}

public class HP{
     public Monster monster;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a solution like this

```
public class HP
{
    private Monster _monster;
   public HP(Monster monster)
    {
        this._monster = monster;
        
    }
    public int Base;

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_monster.Level);
        }
    }
}
```

then the monster class can be like this

```
 public class Monster
{
    public HP hp;
    public int Level;
    public Monster(int level)
    {
        this.Level = 10;//can be set to level ,this is for testing.
        hp = new HP(this);
    }
}
```

This is not a very good solution , you should really consider using inhertance imo.

Comment: Could you please be so kind and show me how to do it property via inheritance? Much appreciated.

Comment: i think @enigmativity just posted the perfect inheritance solution....check that out

Answer (score 0):

You must look into tutorials that explain classes. It is of utmost importance that you understand the concept. `But according to the a little bit of SOLID principle I know, this is a VERY BAD coding!` SOLID comes after you have understood the concepts around classes, structs, properties, interfaces, polymorphism, and acquired a general knowledge of what these things are and how they work. Forget SOLID for now, pick it up again after several months of learning.

Let me show you how to do the code properly:

First of all, you don't use its own class for HP. That makes little to no sense unless you know what you are doing and have a good reason. Keep it simple:

```
public class Monster
{
    public int HP;
    public int MaxHP;
    public int Level;
}
```

You just tried to wrap HP into its own class, and it basically is just an integer anyway.

To answer your question about how to use it:
This is a class that contains some unit information:

```
public class UnitStats
{
    public int HP;
    public int Energy;
    public int Level;
}
```

Now, as of your unit class:

```
public class Monster
{
    public UnitStats Stats;
    public string Name;

    public void Setup (int hp, int level, string name)
    {
        Stats = new UnitStats (); // Create an instance/object of the class.
        Stats.MaxHP = hp; // Set its values.
        Stats.HP = hp;
        Stats.Level = level;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Hint: Do not use an own class for every unit. Find a common class in which you can define every unit.
Hint 2: I intentionally didn't use properties. But normally you never use public fields, only public properties. In Unity you use public fields to expose them in the inspector, this is the only valid case I know of.